# Структура файлов в проекте Android MVP

Tags: android, mvp

Только недавно начал изучать MVP, параллельно практикуясь. Решил создать простенькое приложение с регистрацией через Firebase. Таким образом, у меня появилось четыре вопроса:

1. Какой структуры файлов лучше всего придерживаться? Просто создать папки Model, View, Presenter в com? Это должны быть именно обычные папки? Просто, Android studio предлагает создать только три следующие вещи, которые я могу назвать папками: Package, Android Resource Directory, Data Sample directory.
2. Когда я устанавливал в своё приложение Firebase, создавал возможность логиниться, у меня получилось два файла, содержащие логику: AuthDasboard, который позволяет делать sign in, sign out и delete; И AuthUserData, который собирает данные.

Если я правильно понимаю, эти два класса я должен положить в папку Model, а два активити (MainActivity, LoginActivity) в папку View?

3. В классе AuthDasboard у меня есть метод isUserAuthenticated(), который проверяет, авторизован ли пользователь. Мне необходимо делать setContentView(R.layout.activity_login) или startActivity(LoginActivity); Нормально будет, если оставить это так? Если не ошибаюсь, желательно, чтобы модель ничего не знала о View. Что с этим можно сделать?

Может быть, стоит в презентере вызывать AuthDashboard, и, если возвращается 0, то запускать setContentView?

4. Могу ли я создать в com несколько папок, реализующих разные вещи? Допустим, папку Login и в ней три папки: Model, View, Presenter. И так далее

Comment: Сейчас попробовал в com создать папки Model, View и Presenter. В Model положил AuthDasboard, AuthUserData. В View положил LoginActivity, MainActivity. В Presenter'e создал AuthPresenter, в котором создал два метода: Dashboard и UserData.

В Dasboard вызываю isUserAuthenticated. Если этот метод возвращает 0 - создаю интент и делаю startActivity на LoginActivity. Если возвращает 1 - делаю то же самое, только запускаю уже MainActivity. При сборке всё ок. Однако, при запуске на телефоне - возвращает ошибку во время запуска приложения: NullException. После этого приложение даже запустить нельзя.

Comment: Мне кажется, что сначала стоит понять где создавать папки и что за расположение папок MVP не отвечает. MV* архитектуры скорее про спсоб обмена данными между слоями. 
Советую прочитать цикла мини-статей здесь про чистую архитектуру и там же есть картинка со структурой папок: https://github.com/AndroidArchitecture/AndroidArchitectureBook/blob/master/theory/Theory_article.md

Comment: Ещё меня смутило, что вы создаёте папки внутри com. В Android у каждого приложения есть уникальный идентификатор (он же package для Ваших классов), который выглядит как правило следующим образом: com.<имя_органиизации>.<название_приложения>
Создавать новые папки нужно внутри общего package, то есть внутри папки com.<имя_органиизации>.<название_приложения>. Возможно, что из-за этого прилоежение падает на телефоне

Comment: спасибо огромное за ссылку! Обязательно прочту.

Да. Как вы сказали, я так и делаю (создавал папки не в com, а в com.имя организации.название приложения. Написал просто "com" для экономии места :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Сейчас, у меня самая большая проблема выглядит так:

Я создаю класс AuthDasboard, в котором реализую метод, который проверяет, аутентифицирован ли пользователь; Если не аутентифицирован - делаю setContentView(R.layout.activity_login). 

> В MainActivity создаю экземпляр класса AuthDasboard, и призываю метод isUserAuthenticated. При попытке запустить приложение после сборки получаю очень много логов и ошибку null reference

Comment: Даже если брать только две Activity - 

Если в Activity A вызвать метод Activity B, который делает setContentView(); - я буду получать нуль

Пробовал через startActivity - то же самое